# How do I get headers from a LightTPD CGI app?

Tags: c, http-headers, cgi, url-routing, lighttpd

I have this simple CGI script (which I compile):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Content-Type: text/plain\n\nHello world!\n");
    for(register unsigned short i=argc; i>0;) {
        --i; printf("argv[%d]=%s ", i, argv[i]);
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get any of the header information.

Here are the differences I've made to my default `lighttpd.conf`:

```
server.modules = ("mod_access", "mod_accesslog", "mod_alias",
                  "mod_cgi", "mod_compress",  "mod_status", )

server.port    = 8000

#### CGI module
$HTTP["url"]   =~ "/cgi-bin/" {
    cgi.assign =  ( "" => "" )
}
cgi.assign     =  ( ".cgi"  => "")
```

---

#### How do I get header information and arguments?

BTW: Is this the most efficient way of serving compiled C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both @Stefan's links are broken, so decided to write the answer I found from research:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Content-Type: text/plain\n\nHello world!\n");
    const char *method_str = getenv("REQUEST_METHOD");
    for(register unsigned short i=argc; i>0;) {
        --i; printf("argv[%d]=%s ", i, argv[i]);
    }
    printf("REQUEST_METHOD = %s", method_str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read how [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) works. [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/) is a variant that keeps the backend process running for multiple requests and doesn't involve forking on every request. There are many similar protocols (SCGI, uwsgi, ...).